# In Middle Ages Europe, Physical scientists referred to the "Queen of Sciences"; what was this?

Tags: middle-ages, science

We often hear scientists write of the Queen of Sciences.  To what were they referring?  And is it relevant in today's research?

Comment: Theology was “the queen of the sciences” and philosophy “her handmaiden”. Later Locke declared philosophy "*the handmaiden of the sciences*" and later still Gauss proclaimed:"*Mathematics is the queen of the sciences and number theory is the queen of mathematics.*" Philosophy never got a break.

Comment: If mathematics is the queen, what discipline is the king?

Comment: it hardly matters. These are cringeworthy metaphors. You would make better use of your time actually studying the things you keep referring to as your kings and queens

Comment: @DJohnsonIt mattered to the philosophers and scientists (legitimate scholars) for centuries. Would you discount their research, credibility, contributions?  It is on their shoulders which you stand, eh?

Answer (score 2):

There were at least two Queens:

In the late Middle Ages, Theology was called Queen of the sciences.  See, e.g., ["How Theology Stopped Being Regina Scientiarum—and How Its Story Continues"](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0953946819868092#:%7E:text=That%20theology%20used%20to%20be,vague%20and%20general%2C%20lacking%20precision.)

Subsequently in the 1700s, the title was transferred to mathematics.  E.g., Gauss who said "Mathematics is the queen of the sciences and number theory is the queen of mathematics."

(There's a lot more if you google "Queen of the Sciences"...)

Mathematics is, of course, relevant.  And in some areas -- String Theory, for example -- there seems to be no hope left but prayer...

Comment: Is there an authentic German/Latin quote of Gauss?

Comment: "Die Mathematik ist die Königin der Wissenschaften und die Zahlentheorie ist die Königin der Mathematik." -- attributed to Gauss

Answer (score 1):

There is a much-quoted description of the elaborately sculpted tomb of Isaac Newton, repeated (for instance) in the April 1731 (vol 1, number 4, p.159) issue of [Gentleman's Magazine](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gentleman_s_Magazine_and_Historical_Revi/40QdAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22queen+of+the+sciences%22&pg=PA159&printsec=frontcover), in the year [Westminster Abbey](https://www.westminster-abbey.org/abbey-commemorations/commemorations/sir-isaac-newton) says the statuary was unveiled.

> ... On the globe sits the figure of *Astronomy* weeping, with a sceptre in her hand (as Queen of the Sciences) and a *Star* over her head on the *Pyramid*. ...

Other publications with almost identical descriptions include [The Political State of Great Britain](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hxgf2u&view=1up&seq=428&q1=%22queen%20of%20the%20sciences%22), April 1731, vol. 41, p.412,413; [The Present State of the Republick of Letters](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433087362327&view=1up&seq=325&q1=%22queen%20of%20the%20sciences%22), April 1731, vol. 7, pp.317-320; and [The Pennsylvania Gazette](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.31822008509556&view=1up&seq=572&q1=%22queen%20of%20the%20sciences%22), 22-29 July 1731, No. 141 (p.512 in the 1968 reprint).  The *Republick* version has some added content, including a quotation of Pope's "All Nature and its Laws lay  in Night; God said let *Newton* be, and all was Light".

Astronomy is not far removed from mathematics, and so on, but Q of S can have other meanings than Theology and Mathematics.

Added 7 May 2023:  An earlier English instance is in John Gadbury's 1677 interestingly titled book [The Just and Pious Scorpionist...](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Just_and_Pious_Scorpionist_Or_the_Na/VG5jAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=queen+science&pg=PP8&printsec=frontcover), where the preface (flatteringly titled "To the Honest and Intelligent Reader") states

> For it is the *Divine Urania!* and *she* alone ! that is the *Mistris* and *Queen* of all *Natural Sciences*.

Alas, it is clear that the author means Urania the muse of astrology not astronomy.